# How to disable formatting for FloatField in template for Django

Tags: python, django, templates

i just can't seem to find a definitive answer to this issue, and django's irc needs auth to services...
So my question is : how can you force some kind of formatting for FloatFields in template when you're using Django ?

The problem is simple i need simple dot separated numbers like this : 42547.34
And i end up with comma separated values...

here is a example of template where the problem occurs :

```
{% for point in zone.points.all  %}
  {% if forloop.last %}
    new google.maps.LatLng({{point.latitude|floatformat}},{{point.longitude|floatformat}})
  {% else %} 
    new google.maps.LatLng({{point.latitude|floatformat}},{{point.longitude|floatformat}}),
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}];
```

Thank you for your time.

P.S. i don't have this problem when using the admin generated forms where the floats appear correctly (My locale is en_US)

Comment: Please post the smallest bit of code that shows this problem.  Also, what's your Locale setting?  Is it a locale that uses "," for the decimal place?

Comment: the problem with this code is that it's writing javascript code and the commas are really messing everything up...

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
{{ float_var|stringformat:"f" }}
```

Comment: I had the same problem and this seams to be the easiest solution for generating Javascript compatible floats. For Django > 1.3 there are also the new "localize" / "unlocalize" filters: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/localization/#unlocalize

Comment: `stringformat:"f"` reduces to 6 decimals (e.g. 4.3550434558 becomes 4.355043). @justinhui 's answer not (i.e. using `unlocalize`).

Comment: I think the answers given below are much better and clearer than this. This is only good if you want to customize the output as well. Like to output only two decimal place you can write `|stringformat:".2f"`, but more simpler is to just write `|safe` or to make sure it doesn't localize the output `{% load l10n %}` and then write `|unlocalize `

Comment: Now that we're not just on Django 2.x but 3.x, the `unlocalize` template filter is unquestionably the correct answer.

Answer (score 29):

You can now force the value to be printed without localization.

```
{% load l10n %}

{{ value|unlocalize }}
```

Taken from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/formatting/#std:templatefilter-unlocalize

Comment: Thanks for the answer! IMO this is clearly the most direct way of achieving what's necessary because it disables l10n.. so rather than parsing the string through l10n and then converting it back, you get the programmatic number formatting without the fuzz.

It's also easy to understand what the template filter does.

Last but not least, we don't disable html escaping which should be seen as a sane default.

Comment: This is a clearer approach than the selected answer.

Answer (score 14):

I have a problem rendering lat and lng values.
My solution was:

```
{{ value|safe }}
```

Comment: This is the best option if you don't want to load any extra filter.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a [custom template filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters).

```
from django.template import Library
from django.utils.numberformat import format

register = Library()

@register.filter
def floatdot(value, decimal_pos=4):
    return format(value, ".", decimal_pos)

floatdot.is_safe = True
```

Usage:

`{{ float_var|floatdot }}` or `{{ float_var|floatdot:2 }}`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom `formats.py` (see "[Creating custom format files](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/localization/#creating-custom-format-files)" in the Django docs) and define `THOUSAND_SEPARATOR` and `DECIMAL_SEPARATOR`

```
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = ''
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = '.'
```

This is a global setting, so it will affect all floats displayed on your site. And you'll have to turn on localization (`USE_L10N` in your settings.py).

If you have control over the template, you could simply remove the `floatformat` filter.

**edit**: I'm not sure, but perhaps you are a victim of this Django bug: [#13617](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13617). Try to turn **off** localization support in your settings.py and see if the erroneous commas disappear:

```
USE_L10N = False
```

If that is the case, have a look at the various workarounds mentioned in the bugreport (the simplest being to turn localization off if you don't need it anyway).

Comment: thank you for your answer, but simply removing the filter "floatformat" doesn't work... Should i add another filter ?

Comment: Note: "turning of localization" isn't really a solution when your Django install needs locale support.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same issue, and as piquadrat says, it's an annoying bug related to localization support. Changing `USE_L10N = True` to `False` solve this, it is suppposed to be fix in Django 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

When print some variable for javascrip, its better to jsonify it. Write a jsonify template tag then use

```
{{value|jsonify}}
```

Template tags

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
import json
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

def jsonify(object):
    if isinstance(object, QuerySet):
        return serialize('json', object)
    return json.dumps(object)

register.filter('jsonify', jsonify)
```

Comment: Invalid filter: 'jsonify'

Comment: Sure I did :-) But at the time I made this comment, your answer did not contain any reference to `jsonify`. It doesn't exist by default in the Django framework. It requires an external package to be installed (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-jsonify/) or a custom `jsonify` filter to be written, which you've just included in your updated answer now.

Comment: OK, just add that tags